# Webscraping bs4, cannot figure out how to get a result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am currently trying to scrape the `title = "XFX"` value from:

```
<a class="item-brand" href="https://www.newegg.com/XFX/BrandStore/ID-1669">
                <img alt="XFX" class="lazy-img" data-effect="fadeIn" data-src="//c1.neweggimages.com/Brandimage_70x28//Brand1669.gif" src="//c1.neweggimages.com/WebResource/Themes/2005/Nest/blank.gif" title="XFX">
                </img></a>
```

at the moment i am using this python code to access it, but it cannot be found

```
brand_container = container.findAll("a", {"class":"item-brand"})
    brand = brand_container[0].title
```

I have no clue what to put after brand = brand_container so that it gets the `title =`value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title attribute is under **image** tag not **anchor** tag.You can use `find_all` or css selector `select`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<a class="item-brand" href="https://www.newegg.com/XFX/BrandStore/ID-1669">
                <img alt="XFX" class="lazy-img" data-effect="fadeIn" data-src="//c1.neweggimages.com/Brandimage_70x28//Brand1669.gif" src="//c1.neweggimages.com/WebResource/Themes/2005/Nest/blank.gif" title="XFX">
                </img></a>'''

container=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
brand_container = container.find_all("a", class_="item-brand")
for brand in brand_container:
    print(brand.find_next('img')['title'])
```

---

OR **CSS selector**

```
for brand in container.select(".item-brand>img"):
    print(brand['title'])
```